# Produce waveform video from audio using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a waveform video from audio. My goal is to produce a video that looks something like this

[image]

For my test I have an mp3 that plays a short clipped sound. There are 4 bars of 1/4 notes and 4 bars of 1/8 notes played at 120bpm. I am having some trouble coming up with the right combination of preprocessing and filtering to produce a video that looks like the image. The colors dont have to be exact, I am more concerned with the shape of the beats. I tried a couple of different approaches using showwaves and showspectrum. I cant quite wrap my head around why when using showwaves the beats go past so quickly, but using showspectrum produces a video where I can see each individual beat.

**ShowWaves**

```
ffmpeg -i beat_test.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x100:mode=cline:rate=25:scale=sqrt,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a output_wav.mp4
```

This [link](https://mega.nz/#!NvowgKaZ!wgMZv2mSBUZDTS-5SWHULYQ2UDCwRT7ZwHR8Alwbu1k) will download the output of that command.

**ShowSpectrum**

```
ffmpeg -i beat_test.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=s=1280x100:mode=combined:color=intensity:saturation=5:slide=1:scale=cbrt,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -an -map 0:a output_spec.mp4
```

This [link](https://mega.nz/#!Q3g0TYgA!QWGssnyZZXjCLGlvrIWK9stwNPcu5MqTC3E5rGgBfrY) will download the output of that command.

*I posted the simple examples because I didn't want to confuse the issue by adding all the variations I have tried.*

In practice I suppose I can get away with the output from showspectrum but I'd like to understand where/how I am thinking about this incorrectly. Thanks for any advice.

Here is a [link](https://mega.nz/#!4qoxWYrY!Bq36Hr3pKDZxfprP_YgqlKpZo3Frj8RvZPi47EPbgNQ) to the source audio file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the download links are no longer working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `showwaves` does is show the waveform in realtime, and the display window is 1/framerate i.e. if the video output is 25 fps, then each frame shows the waveform of 40 ms of audio. There's no 'history' or 'memory' so you can't (directly) get a scrolling output like it seems your reference video shows.

The workaround for this is to use the `showwavespic` filter to produce a single frame showing the entire waveform at a high enough horizontal resolution. Then do a scrolling overlay of that picture over a desired background, at a speed such that the scroll lasts as long as the audio.

Basic command template would be:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.png -loop 1 -i wavespic.png -i audio.mp3
 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=W-w*t/mp3dur:y=SOMEFIXEDVALUE" -shortest waves.mp4
```

`mp3dur` above should be replaced with the duration of the audio file.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I created the wavespic, and a background image. Then I ran ffmpeg providing this filter:

    "[0][1]overlay=W-w*t/16:y=0"

Let me see if  understand that correctly. It should apply the overlay filter to the second input. The main width is set to the overlay width multiplied by time divided by length of audio. 

I tried to position the overlay so that it starts in the center of the screen, but add the "x" parameter seems to fix it in place.

Comment: In my command, `W-w*t/mp3dur` is x expression. To start from center: `W/2-w*t/mp3dur`

Comment: I was playing around it, and came up with this scrolling bar design : 
`color=c=black:s=2x360[bar]; [1][bar]overlay=x='main_w*t/MP3_DURATION-overlay_w/2':y=0 [spectro1]; [grid][spectro1] overlay=x=0:y=0 [spectro2]; [0][spectro2]overlay=x='max(min(main_w/2-overlay_w*t/MP3_DURATION,0), main_w-overlay_w)':y=0`.
You can prepend this with `showwavespic=s=WIDTHxHEIGHT:colors=#9cf42f, drawbox=x=(iw-w)/2:y=(ih-h)/2:w= iw:h=1:color=#9cf42f [1];` to generate the waveform on the fly too, although remember to keep this width much larger than the video's, so that the bar actually scrolls.